# Polygonizing only pixel values of 1 from raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, vector, polygonize

I have a raster mask that I have created in QGIS (2.2.0) that consist of 0, 1 and nodata values.  I would like to end up with a polygon dataset that consist of only the value of one pixels from this same raster dataset.  I have tried the polygonize tool, but it doesn't seem to be producing what I am looking for as it is taking both the 0 and 1 pixel values into the polygons.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Why not poligonize the whole raster and remove the values you're not interested in?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Micheal.  This does seem like a good course of action to reach my goal.  Sometimes the best solutions are the most simple.  This works Raster --> Conversion --> Polygonize (Raster to Vector) and get a vector layer.

Comment: You're welcome. You could also try to set the NoData value to 0 if there are no other values besides 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SAGA tool [Vectorising grid classes](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/shapes_grid_6.html). Just set Class Selection to One Single Class and set Class Identifier to 1.

[image: vectorising_grid_classes_snapshot]